# Form is not responding after event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having this problem that my form would show up but not responding after it detects an event.

[image: buttons and text won't show]

Here's my code for listening the event and what it does after it detects the event.

```
private void checkPrintJobs()
    {
        EventLogQuery logQuery = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational", PathType.LogName, "*[System[(EventID = 800)]]");
        EventLogWatcher logWatcher = new EventLogWatcher(logQuery);
        logWatcher.EventRecordWritten += new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(EventWritten);
        logWatcher.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void EventWritten(Object obj, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
    {
        PrintQueue myPrintQueue = new PrintQueue(ps, printer, PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministratePrinter);
        myPrintQueue.Pause();
        foreach (var job in myPrintQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())
        {
            job.Pause();

        }
        MessageBox.Show("WAIT!");

        frmPromptPIN frm = new frmPromptPIN(printer);
        frm.Show();

    }
```

If i removed the MessageBox.Show("WAIT!"), the form won't show up at all.
Anyone experiencing this one?

Comment: Those events arrive on a secondary thread and your code is attempting to show a form that should be invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: Is `EventWritten` located in a Form? Because you're going to need a Control that you can invoke from. I will extrapolate in an answer....

Comment: Yes, the following code is under a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TnTinMn says you have to invoke your UI code in the UI thread, eg.

```
private void EventWritten(Object obj, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
{
    PrintQueue myPrintQueue = new PrintQueue(ps, printer, PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministratePrinter);
    myPrintQueue.Pause();
    foreach (var job in myPrintQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())
    {
        job.Pause();

    }

    Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
         frmPromptPIN frm = new frmPromptPIN(printer);
         frm.Show();
    });

}
```

Comment: i'm just new to c# or programming overall and i just learned something new. now it works flawlessly. thanks!